# Regex: optional-ignore double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I have a question about matching groups based on the following regular expression

```
static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w+)\s*(?<Value>.*)$";
```

Sample Data as following:

```
   TEST_REPLICATE
    {
        REPLICATE_ID            1986
        ASSAY_NUMBER            877
        ASSAY_VERSION           4
        ASSAY_STATUS            "Research"
            }
```

I am able to retrieve values correctly and if values are  NULL, it works correctly as well. What I am trying to do is to also retrieve a value for instance the last one module which is in double quotes.  I am not really sure if i am doing it correctly, would this be the correct regex for the above scenario, I just added quotes before w. Please correct, thanks

```
  static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\"w+)\s*(?<Value>.*)$";
```

Comment: Doesn't your original expression already match such values?

Comment: You want quotes stripped from value?

Comment: @Qtax, You are right it works, the existing regex works too, i just didnt have the node in it ,thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where your problem is. This works for me:

```
\s*(?<Key>[^\s]+)\s*(?<Value>.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You regex is not correct.Atleast for the input you have provided..

If I have understood your question,this is the regex that you need.

```
^\s*(?<Key>\w+)\s*\"?(?<Value>.*?)\"?$
```

It would work with `multiline` mode...